# How to use GetX for data passing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

My first Flutter development with GetX. Now encounter a problem.
I have a ListView where the items are all encapsulated Class.
The requirement now is to create an obs List as a data source. The elements in the List are all models.
I now want to pass the model in the List to the item, and click on the item to pass it to the next page for data modification. what should I do?
I am like this

`

```
Controller：
class FindQADetailController extends GetxController {
  var detailEntity = QADetailEntity().obs;
}


Page：
class FindQAPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FindQAPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FindQAPage> createState() => _FindQAPageState();
}

class _FindQAPageState extends BasePageMixin<FindQAPage, FindQAPresenter>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
    implements FindQAIView {
  final findQAController = Get.put(FindQAController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _refresh();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RezaAppContainer(
      childWidget: Obx(() => DeerListView(
          itemCount: findQAController.listData.length,
          onRefresh: _refresh,
          loadMore: _loadMore,
          hasMore: findQAController.hasMore,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            var entity = findQAController.listData[index];
            return FindItemQAPage(entity);
          })),
    );
  }

Item：
class FindItemQAPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FindItemQAPage(this.entity, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  QAEntity entity;

  @override
  State<FindItemQAPage> createState() => _FindItemQAPageState();
}

class _FindItemQAPageState
    extends BasePageMixin<FindItemQAPage, FindItemQAPresenter>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
    implements FindItemQAIView {
  FindItemQAController findItemQAController = Get.put(FindItemQAController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    findItemQAController.entity.value = widget.entity;
  }

  }
```

`

I want the elements in the array in the first page to be passed to the item and the next page, and the data modifications made on the next page to be passed to the item in the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Passing Data from 1st Screen to 2nd Screen
You can pass any data using `arguments` parameters in navigation methods

```
Get.to(ScreenName(),arguments: PASS_DATA);
```

If you are doing navigation with routes still you can pass data

```
Get.toNamed(RoutesName, arguments: PASS_DATA);
```

For navigate data back from 2nd screen to 1st screen you can user result property.

```
Get.back(result:PASS_DATA);
```

Pass data from 1st screen to 2nd screen & vice versa.

**1st screen controller**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class FirstController extends GetxController {
  /// Navigation method.
  Future<void> btnNavigateTap() async {
    //.... Using Get.toNamed method || use this if you are using routeName
   //.... Pass Data from 1st screen to 2nd screen
    Get.toNamed(
      SeconScreenRouteName,
      arguments: {
        "user": "Jems",
        "emails": ["abc@gmail.com", "pqr@gmail.com"],
      },
    );

    //.... Using Get.to method
   //.... Pass Data from 1st screen to 2nd screen
    Get.to(
      SecondScreen(),
      arguments = {
        "user": "Jems",
        "emails": ["abc@gmail.com", "pqr@gmail.com"],
      },
    );

   //.... Get Data from 2nd screen to 1st screen
   final result = await Get.to(
      SecondScreen(),
      arguments = {
        "user": "Jems",
        "emails": ["abc@gmail.com", "pqr@gmail.com"],
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**2nd screen controller to access data.**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
                    
class SecondController extends GetxController {
  late String user;
  late List<String> emails;
   dynamic argumentData;

   @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    user = argumentData['user'];
    emails = argumentData['emails'];
  } 
  
  void btnBackTap(){
    //... Passing data to previous screen.
    Get.back(result:{
     "user":"Jack",
    });
  }
    
}
```

For more details about navigation & parsing data using getX check this [reference link](https://medium.com/@iamrutudhvaj/getx-flutter-b3781be2b644)